# Detect a tap on the status bar control in .net CF 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework

I am developing a C# application using Windows 6 professional mobile device. I want to detect an event when the user taps on the status bar and then display a list box. The .NET CF status bar has no key down or events other than Text changed or parent changed. How do I approach this problem?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I've not actually tried this so YMMV, but if I had to solve the problem, I'd likely try to subclass the parent form and look for mouse messages in the region where the StatusBar is.  There's [an article in MSDN magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188736.aspx) that covers subclassing Forms in the Compact Framework that should get you 95% of the way there.

Answer (score 0):

On the off chance that you are talking about the Soft [Input Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsce.forms.inputpanel%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), you have to add a reference to `Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms`, then drop an Input Panel control onto your form.

C++ example code here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/264034

Basically, just wire up the only event for the `Input Panel` control. I did something like this not too long ago:

```
void SIP_EnabledChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  int locationY = Y_START; // defined as txtNote.Location.Y when the form loads
  if (inputPanel1.Enabled) {
    locationY -= inputPanel1.Bounds.Height;
  }
  txtNote.SuspendLayout();
  txtNote.Bounds = new Rectangle(
    txtNote.Location.X,
    locationY,
    txtNote.Size.Width,
    txtNote.Size.Height
  );
  txtNote.ResumeLayout();
  txtNote.Refresh();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Control.Capture should help you:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.capture%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

In your Form's constructor set the Capture property to True:

```
this.Capture = true;
```

Then add mouse event handlers to your Form.
E.g.:

```
// This method handles the mouse down event for all the controls on the form.  
// When a control has captured the mouse
// the control's name will be output on label1.
private void Control_MouseDown(System.Object sender, 
    System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Control control = (Control) sender;
    if (control.Capture)
    {
        label1.Text = control.Name+" has captured the mouse";
    }
}
```

It will be raised even the child control got click.